# What does the term lowest stable nonedescript mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, charles-dickens

As to the latter, when every posting-house and ale-house could produce somebody in “the Captain’s” pay, ranging from the landlord to the lowest stable nondescript, it was the likeliest thing upon the cards.The preceding sentence is from Dickens' A Tale of Two Cities' chap2. What does 'lowest stable nondescript' mean?

Comment: Hello, anjan. A Google search for << "lowest stable nondescript" -Dickens -landlord >> gives 1 result, but still the Dickens quote. This indicates that the string isn't a fixed phrase, and the words can be looked up individually. 'Lowest' is a variant of 'lowliest' here.

Answer (score 3):

Among the inn staff, the landlord would be the most important and a boy working in the stable the least important. *Nondescript* means 'lacking in any distinctive or interesting features'.